# How do I get input from the Oculus remote?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus

I am trying to figure out how to use the oculus remote in Unity3D 5.3.4f. I've found some  [documentation](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/game-engines/latest/concepts/unity-ovrinput/#unity-ovrinput-rift-remote) about OVR mapping, but I can't seem to figure it out.

What I want to achieve is when the middle button(Button.One) is clicked.

What I now use is this line of code

```
if (OVRInput.GetUp(OVRInput.Button.One))
    {
        Debug.Log("remote click");
    }
```

But when I run the application I get this error.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   OVRInput.GetUp (Button virtualMask, Controller controllerMask) (at Assets/OVR/Scripts/OVRInput.cs:600)
>   menuButtonHandler.Update () (at Assets/menuButtonHandler.cs:136)

Which can be found in this script

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the current up state of the given virtual button mask with the given controller mask.
/// Returns true if any masked button was released this frame on any masked controller and no other masked button is still down this frame.
/// </summary>
public static bool GetUp(Button virtualMask, Controller controllerMask = Controller.Active)
{
    return OVRManager.input.GetResolvedButtonUp(virtualMask, RawButton.None, controllerMask);
}
```

Has anyone used to Oculus remote controller before in unity and can help me out?

Thank you,

Johan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the objects in that method likely needs to be initialized before you make the GetUp() call.

Take a close look at your init code, and any samples you may have -- I bet you'll find something missing after not too much looking.  I'm not familiar with the Unity APIs, but if they are anything like the PC or mobile C++ APIs, chances are you missed a step, or forgot to start up the VR service.

Comment: Thankyou for an answer.

I've placed my code all the way to the end of the scriptfile. But still it doesn't seem to work. Really weird stuff

Comment: Nevermind, found the solution. I was working with the wrong camera prefab. you must use the OVRcameracontroller from within the package.

Answer (score 1):

To work with the input in the Unity Version 2017.1.1 you have first to download the "Oculus Utilities for Unity"

[Oculus Utilities asset package for Unity](https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/package/oculus-utilities-for-unity-5/)

Then you have to import the package in Unity,
Go to: 
-- "Asset"  -->  "Import package"  -->  "Custom package"
[image: Oculus Utility package]

Browse your "Oculus Utilities download"
[image]

Click on import

Call the function "OVRInput.update()" before calling the input checking functions.

```
void Update ()
    {
        OVRInput.Update(); // Call before checking the input

        if (OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.DpadLeft)) {
            print("left button pressed");
        }
        if (OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.DpadRight)) {
            print("right button pressed");
        }
        if (OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.One)) {
            print("round button pressed");
        }
    }
```

For more information about the OVRInput check this link

[OVRInput](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/latest/concepts/unity-ovrinput/)